# How to strip away vector container and return an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, scope

When reading in files, it's convenient to allocate the memory via a vector:

```
someType* readCSV() {
    std::vector<someType> vec;
    someType x;
    ...
    while(fscanf(f, parser, &x) != EOF) {
        vec.push_back(x);
        getc(f); // skip comma
    }
    return &vec[0];
}
```

But I just want to return an normal array (I'm working with CUDA afterwards whose API uses pointers).

So the question is whether `vec` going out of scope at the end of the function call will destroy the data it contains, and if there is anything I can do preserve it.

Comment: Where is `vec` defined?

Comment: You could always allocate the `vector` outside of `readFile` and pass it in as an argument by reference.

Comment: True, but that's a bit messy in the sense it ruins encapsulation. The users shouldn't have to know that the function is implemented using vectors.

Comment: Yes, `vec` and the data it contains will be destroyed when the function returns. I suggest returning `vec` by value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot allocate memory in a function and not loosing it without the need to clean it up afterwards.

You could wrap the function into a class which stores the vector. Then you are able to return the pointer and the data will persist.

```
class csvReader
{
public:
  csvReader (void) {}
  type* readCSV (void)
  {
    type x;
    while(fscanf(f, parser, &x) != EOF) {
      vec.push_back(x);
      getc(f); // skip comma
    }
    return vec.data();
  }
private:
  std::vector<type> vec;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to how you declared it then the vector is allocated on stack hence the reference you return will become invalid when going out of scope.

You can have many solutions:

- pass a vector to the function so that the caller is responsible for its allocation and deallocation
- use a dynamic array (like `someType *array = new someType[vec.size()]` and you will be responsible of deallocating it through `delete[] array`
- returning the vector itself so that it is pushed onto the stack and not deallocated upon exiting the function (`return vec`)

Comment: With regards to dynamic array, won't that just create new memory completely separate from the vector?